# Why does removing multiprocessing from my program throws an "A float is needed" error in math.sin() function?

Tags: python, floating-point, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have implemented my program earlier by multiprocessing but now I am using Numba so I want to remove multiprocessing. But, I am having some problem.
The part of the program is given here, I am using spyder version 3.2.8 which is using python 2.7.

```
theta = 0
sin_theta = math.sin(math.radians(theta))
```

Multiprocessing is implemented as follows

```
dataset = []  
for i in range(0, 375, 15):
    for j in range(0, 195, 15):
        for k in range(0, 375, 15):
            dataset.append([i, j, k])


agents = 40
chunksize = 4
pool = mp.Pool(processes = agents)
result = pool.map(calling, dataset, chunksize)
```

After removing multiprocessing as follows

```
import os
dataset = []  
for i in range(0, 375, 15):
    for j in range(0, 195, 15):
        for k in range(0, 375, 15):
            dataset.append([i, j, k])


calling(dataset)
```

Calling funtion is

```
def calling(dataset):
    l1 = dataset[0]
    l2 = dataset[1]
    l3 = dataset[2]


    import random
    i = random.sample(range(9000), 1)


    t = 0
    f = 0
    z = 0


    global g_r
    global g_o


    g_o_r = grid_one
    global s_a_r, p_l
    rt(p_l, l1, l2, l3, i)
```

The rt function is

```
def rt(p, f, t, z, i):
    import math
    import cmath
    sin_t = math.sin(math.radians(t))
    sin_f = math.sin(math.radians(f))
    sin_z = math.sin(math.radians(z))
    cos_t = math.cos(math.radians(t))
    cos_f = math.cos(math.radians(f))
    cos_z = math.cos(math.radians(z))
```

The error is

```
sin_t = math.sin(math.radians(t))
TypeError: a float is required
```

Please tell if any further info or data is required.

Comment: Not being the downvoter, I assume they did it because the two code snippets do not show how multiprocessing and the `math.sin()` are related in your program, thus giving your question low quality. We cannot answer it with the information you gave us. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the full Traceback in order for SO to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataset` is a list of lists with three elements each. When using multiprocessing and passing your `dataset` via `pool.map` the outer list was iterated and the three-element inner lists were passed to `calling`.

Hence, when you did:

```
l1 = dataset[0]
l2 = dataset[1]
l3 = dataset[2]
```

l1, l2 and l3 each contained one of the three elements of an inner list.

Now that you directly pass `dataset` to `calling`, l1, l2, and l3 hold the first three inner lists of your `dataset`, so basically you pass the lists `[0, 0, 0]`, `[0, 0, 15]` and `[0, 0, 30]` down to `math.radians()`, hence the error.

To fix that, simply call `calling` like so:

```
for inner in dataset:
    calling(inner)
```